# Java setting button values on memory game

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, match

I have been working on a memory game i asked a question about yesterday, I got some brilliant suggestions but none of them seem to be helping my problem i can get the buttons to shuffle around the grid layout fine, but i cannot figure out how to keep the set values i tried using "setActionCommand" but i don't think this is the way i can do it for matching the values of two buttons within my memory game.

```
    gameBtn[0].setActionCommand("1");
    gameBtn[1].setActionCommand("2");
    gameBtn[2].setActionCommand("3");
    gameBtn[3].setActionCommand("4");
    gameBtn[4].setActionCommand("5");
    gameBtn[5].setActionCommand("6");
    gameBtn[6].setActionCommand("7");
    gameBtn[7].setActionCommand("8");
    gameBtn[8].setActionCommand("1");
    gameBtn[9].setActionCommand("2");
    gameBtn[10].setActionCommand("3");
    gameBtn[11].setActionCommand("4");
    gameBtn[12].setActionCommand("5");
    gameBtn[13].setActionCommand("6");
    gameBtn[14].setActionCommand("7");
    gameBtn[15].setActionCommand("8");
```

above is how i used the setActionCommand but i cant find out how you would compare them to each other to find a match for example matching club1 to diamond1 and club2 to diamond2. would this not mean i would have to do something like this for every single match i wanted?.

```
    if (gameBtn[0].getActionCommand().equals(gameBtn[8].getActionCommand())){
        sameValues();

    }      

    if (gameBtn[1].getActionCommand().equals(gameBtn[9].getActionCommand())){
        sameValues();

    }
```

although the above might seem to work as it does not throw any errors im left thinking there must be a more efficient better way to do it i accomplished this at first before i added the shuffle to move the buttons on the grid i was using another list of values, but know its randomized the card on the button no longer actually matches the buttons set value.

have a look at the link at the bottom of the question if you need more information from my last question, Any help would be much appreciated as this has been bugging me for a while know thank you.

link: [Java concentrate is there a way to shuffle jbuttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608059/java-concentrate-is-there-a-way-to-shuffle-jbuttons)

Comment: Why would you expect the string `"club1"` to equal `"diamond1"`?

Comment: Why you compare string with JButton?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy good catch I didn't even see that

Comment: `getActionCommand` returns the string in which you `setActionCommand()` with

Comment: it is just matching the number and not the suit. what i am trying to accomplish is to match the two buttons themselves given there own values this was one of the suggestions from my last question i tried to set each button its own value.

Comment: If you want to keep the string `"club1"` and `"diamond1"` for some reason unknown to us, just compare the last character. `String ac = gameBtn[0].getActionCommand(); char c1 = ac.charAt(ac.length() - 1);`

Comment: In the game, it doesn't matter the suit right? The suit is only determined by the image. So you should set the action command the same for two button. Like for button 0 and 8, set the action command to `"1"`. Unless you need to reference that the card is a diamond or a club, then just go with my suggestion above (comparing the last character)

Comment: no thats not what i want to do i am just trying to find out if this is the most efficent way to do it with every jbutton if i wanted to just match a number could i not just grab it from where my icon is set. p.s. i am fairly new to java and just trying to teach my self some things with this small project

Comment: You're missing ".getASctionCommand()" from the right side of the equals. Eg, .equals(gameBtn[8].getActionCommand()   If you're worried about knowing when you don't have a match, set a boolean flag to false before making any comparisons, then set it to true if a match occurs.  Or maybe you could use an if..else setup.

Comment: ok thanks @Roy I may just be overthinking it, I will just try getting it fully working this way like that.